# Comma placement in a series

Tags: punctuation, commas

> A high-energy country music that emerged in the 1940s, bluegrass features acoustic stringed instruments, **such as:** the fiddle, banjo, mandolin, guitar, and upright bass.
>
> F) No Change
>   G) instruments, such as
>   H) instruments: such as
>   J) instruments such as,

Can someone help me understand why the answer is G and not J?

Comment: In future questions, you need to do some of your own research. Don't just copy these questions and ask, "Why is the answer A and not B?" See [_Details, Please_...](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) on meta for more question tips.

Comment: I did do my own research and failed to come up with an answer. I only post here as an option of last resort.

Comment: In multiple choice questions you sometimes have to pick the least bad answer. J.R. has got the correct reason it's not J, and that answers your question, and I have given him a thumb-up for it. But I would re-write the entire sentence. Bluegrass is a high-energy country music that emerged in the 1940s. It features acoustic stringed instruments such as: the fiddle, banjo, mandolin, guitar, and upright bass

Comment: @user27343 - The point is, you should tell us what you looked for, and tell us what you found (or didn't find). Otherwise, you create the appearance that you are coming here instead of doing research. (Notice how, when you hover over the downvote button, a tooltip appears; it reads: "This question does not show any research effort.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *such as* is not part of the series.

Check out [this website](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-use-commas-in-a-series/), and pay particular attention to the part that says:

- **Never put a comma in front of the first item on the list.**